# How to solve 'django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied'?

Tags: python, django

**After I setted local default variates in .env file of django project [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLebe.png) and got these in setting.py.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFftt.png)  'django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied' this error happended when running server.

But when I directly gave database's value in setting.py rather than using os.envrion.get(),server worked.How do solve it if using os.envrion.get() to connect database?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and have a look at [ask]. As described there please do not upload images of code / errors.

Comment: It seems you have specified a `.env` file, do you use some package / library to load it's contents to your environment? Do note that just having a `.env` file doesn't mean its contents are environment variables.